# Fire an event on input.checked=true/false _without_ jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the following code (http://jsfiddle.net/FW36F/1/):

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="alert(this.checked)">
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked=!document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked;">toggle</button>
```

If you click the checkbox, you get an alert telling you if it's checked or not.  Great.  However, if you click the toggle button, the checkbox changes it's checked state but the onchange event is NOT fired.

Essentially, the onchange for a checkbox only fires if the user actually clicks the checkbox, *not* if the checkbox is changed via JavaScript.  This is be true in IE, FF, and Chrome.  It appears that this behavior is to specification also.

However, I really need some kind of event to fire if, for any reason, the checkbox's checked state changes.  Is this possible?

Oh yeah, and **jQuery is not allowed**.  And please no setTimeout/setInterval based solutions either...

**Update:** Also, I should make it clear that the code above is for illustration only.  In the real code, we need to ensure the state of the checkbox is checked or unchecked -- not just toggle it.  Perhaps this would be better code to illustrate that:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="alert(this.checked)">
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked=true;">check</button> 
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked=false;">un check</button>
```

Moreover, there may be code in other areas we don't fully control, which might do a simple .checked=true/false -- we'd like to make sure we see that also.

Comment: jQuery would not fire the native change event just by setting its value

Comment: What's wrong with timeouts? I don't think there's anything else that will work.

Comment: @Jivings: I cannot believe you actually asked what is wrong with polling using a timeout. It's like throwing cycles away,and adding a delay to when you're notified. The less delay, the more you waste CPU cycles. There are plenty of answers here that satisfy the OP's requirement

Comment: @JuanMendes Not with the restrictions he's imposed on the solution. He wants to know when the `checked` property changes.

Comment: @jivings That is true, I did not see part where the OP says some other parts of the code may just set `checked=true` directly. With that caveat, polling is the only answer. Except in FF, where you can use `Object.watch` See addition to my answer.

Comment: @JuanMendes Agreed. Does the `onpropertychanged` event still exist anywhere?

Comment: @Jivings: `onpropertychange` does work for IE, so we have a solution for both IE and FF, though they both use non-standards. http://jsfiddle.net/PPuZ8/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The existing answers work just fine, even with your *update*.  Just be smart about it and don't call click if you don't need to. Also, please don't use inline JS. That was OK 10 years ago.

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="alert(this.checked)">
<button id='check'>check</button> 
<button id='uncheck'>uncheck</button>

document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
   if (!this.checked) {
      this.click();
   }
}
```

If you need to be modified  when a script changes the value, in Firefox, you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/PPuZ8/

```
// In FF $ is a shortcut for document.getElementById
// It doesn't fire when set from the UI, you have to use a regular handler for that
$('cb').watch("checked", function(){
   console.log('Checked state changed from script', arguments);
   return true;
});
```

For IE you can use `onpropertychange` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx  (Thanks to jivings for the reminder)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PPuZ8/1/

```
document.getElementById('cb').onpropertychange = function() {    
    if (event.propertyName == 'checked') {
       console.log('Checked state changed onproperty change');    
    }
};
```

For other browsers, you have to poll using setInterval/setTimeout

Comment: @joelarson: Care to comment? This solves the problem for 2 of the 4 major browsers.

Comment: This seems to now be a collection of answers so +1 from me.

Comment: @JuanMendes - thank you for the effort you put into this. I think you've covered all the bases, and something like your first code block is in the end what I went with.  We are going to require specifically calling a setCheck function to check/uncheck in javascript, and if other coders forget and just `ele.checked=true/false`, sad about that. FWIW, I only used inline JavaScript for this example, not in general :P

Answer (score 2):

Have the toggle button actually *click* the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="alert(this.checked)">
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click()">
  toggle
</button>
```

If you wanted any change to the checkbox to inform you of its new position, then I would create a global method for changing the value of the checkbox, and deal with it as a proxy:

```
<script>
function toggleCB( state ) {
  var cb = document.getElementById("cb");
  arguments.length ? cb.checked = state : cb.click() ;
  return cb.checked;
}
</script>
<input id="cb" type="checkbox" />
<input type="button" onClick="alert( toggleCB(true) )" value="Check" />
<input type="button" onClick="alert( toggleCB(false) )" value="Uncheck" />
<input type="button" onClick="alert( toggleCB() )" value="Toggle" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Now anytime you set or toggle the checkbox, you'll get the checked state back.

One last thing, I would avoid using the `onClick` attribute, and instead bind the click events up from within your JavaScript.

Comment: Good suggestion _BUT_ we need to make sure that if other code we don't control does a checked=true/false that we catch that also.  Moreover, we don't really just need a toggle as my example may have misled -- we need explicitly setting true or false.

Comment: @larson4 Sorry, but it was a bad question then.

Comment: @larson4 I would encourage you to use a proxy method to click the checkbox then.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - The thing is we don't 100% control the code which might check the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click)

```
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked=!document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();">toggle</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

oninput is the event you need to handle ... 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input