# Call function on click on Bootstrap toggle (checkbox)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I want to call a function `updateText()` when I click on the checkbox `text_mode`. I've tried using `onClick="updateText()"` but it didn't work. I have read some comments on similar questions, but all answers are using jQuery, can I do it without using any libraries, because all the js code for this project is done without any libraries?

This is the checkbox:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="default" id="text_mode" onclick="updateText()">
</label>
```

Comment: You could use an `onchange="updateText()"` event handler

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap, I'm 99% sure you have jQuery already loaded and ready to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fire an event on input.checked=true/false \_without\_ jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637801/fire-an-event-on-input-checked-true-false-without-jquery)

Comment: Yes, that's true, but in the whole code for updateText() function (and whole js file) I was using pure js, so it wouldn't be good to use jquery just for one function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `onchange` event

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" checked ... onchange="updateText()"> Braille
</label>
```

That will execute it regardless of clicking the checkbox. So if you trigger the label it will also be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById('text_mode').addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log('updateText executed')
});
```

```html
<label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="default" id="text_mode"> Braille
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.5, the same problems. Added an event call to the library:

```
$(document).on('touch.bs.toggle click.bs.toggle', 'div[data-toggle^=toggle]', function (e) {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')
    $checkbox.bootstrapToggle('toggle')
    $checkbox.trigger("click")    // <!-- Added line
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

My problem was solved.